# An error while parsing JSON in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tried to parse JSON with JQuery:

```
$.getJSON('php/getchannelstat.php?id=57', function(myarray) {
```

The file is:

```
{"label":"Test","data":[[1469037397,2],[1469037400,2],[1469037601,2],[1469039401,4],[1469041201,5],[1469043001,5],[1469044801,5],[1469113202,3],[1469115001,3],[1469115998,4],[1469116218,3],[1469116266,3],[1469116281,3],[1469116297,3],[1469116322,3],[1469116330,3],[1469116801,3],[1469118601,4],[1469120401,3],[1469122201,4]] }
```

Can't find any syntax errors, but it says:

```
Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 324
```

(in the last symbols)
What can be wrong with this?

Comment: Can you show the entire function? Maybe the error is there. Same happens if you just console.log the result?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the posted JSON, so if you're getting unexpected characters in your JSON, chances are the server isn't returning what you think it is.

Comment: Works fine for me: `$.parseJSON('{"label":"Test","data":[[1469037397,2],[1469037400,2],[1469037601,2],[1469039401,4],[1469041201,5],[1469043001,5],[1469044801,5],[1469113202,3],[1469115001,3],[1469115998,4],[1469116218,3],[1469116266,3],[1469116281,3],[1469116297,3],[1469116322,3],[1469116330,3],[1469116801,3],[1469118601,4],[1469120401,3],[1469122201,4]] }')`